# Uploading video to YouTube using Dropbox public link?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, gdata, dropbox

I am using youtube **ZEND gdata api** to upload videos to My youtube account.But now I need to upload videos to YouTube which are stored in my DropBox account.I have public links or direct links for video files.Code I am using is:

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_App_Exception');

$developerKey = '******************';
$applicationId = '*********';
$clientId = '';

  $video_title = 'test movie';
  $video_description = 'test movie';
  $video_category = 'Entertainment';
  $video_tags = 'test,movie';
  $path_of_uploaded_file = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/uhh/336/test.wmv';



$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
              $username = '*****',
              $password = '*****',
              $service = 'youtube',
              $client = null,
              $source = '*******', // a short string identifying your application
              $loginToken = null,
              $loginCaptcha = null,
              $authenticationURL);

$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);

$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient);

// create a new VideoEntry object
$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

// create a new Zend_Gdata_App_MediaFileSource object
$filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource($path_of_uploaded_file);

..
.
.
.
.
.?>
```

Error I am getting is:**File to be uploaded at http://dl.dropbox.com/uhh/336/test.wmv does not exist or is not readable.**

I don't why YouTube is throwing this error even though the URL is direct(Public) link. I am not getting what's wrong with my code and why it is not working.Please help  :)

Comment: you do realise clicking that link throws a 404 right ?

Comment: Make sure you have the right link. See if you can access the video by pointing your browser to the link

Comment: @Luke and xbonez The link above is just an example of dropbox link.I did not specify the original url here.But i am using the original url in my code

Comment: A little offtopic, but Blip.tv has a feature to load video's from Dropbox and spread them to all kinds of sites like Youtube (and many many others) automatically.
[edit] Nevermind.. As of december 1st Blip discontinued the connection with Dropbox.. [/edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case other are still looking for answers, I had a similar problem reading txt files with an app I wrote from Dropbox. I discovered that I wasn't using the right direct-link format. The correct link (for this threads example link) would be:

dl.dropboxusercontent.com/uhh/336/test.wmv

Just changing 'www' to 'dl' will work for web-browser as they handle redirects automatically. For apps and scripts you would have to integrate handling of redirects. Or just format the direct-link correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer this question definitively given the information provided, but we can narrow it down to a few possibilities.  I would recommend you run down this quick debugging checklist:

- If you copy/paste that exact link into your web browser, using the same credentials, are you able to download the video?

  - If not, then it's either a problem with the credentials or the URL itself.
  - If you are able to download it from the browser, then it means there's something wrong with your code or an issue with YouTube.

If you run through the above steps but you're still at an impasse, please post your results as a comment and we'll delve deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The file you're uploading to YouTube must be on a local path.

1. Download the file locally using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
2. Set newMediaFileSource to the local file's path

Answer (score 0):

In dropbox "get link" gives "link of dropbox page".

Try this.

1. Open up video page on dropbox.
2. right click on "download" and then "copy link location"

Hope this helps